# Echo not retrieving info from advanced custom fields. Typo?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

For my blog posts on my wordpress page i wanted in-content advertising that leads mostly towards other sections of my site. Its works fine as it gets the most reason post from the custom post type 'advertising' to display with the shortcode [in-content]. However last thing i wanted to do is to use advanced custom fields to either have a drop down to select the desired page it should link to, or fill in a custom url. That's the part where it stops working. Whenever i type `echo $buttonURL` it crashes my site. Do i have a typo somewhere? I have checked ACF in wordpress multiple times and it does work when i manually replace it with either one of them such as `get_field('page_link')`. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or help me out a little.

Ps. I'll remove the inline styling at a later point when I'm completely done with it. Also I'm more used to including php in html instead of vice versa. However the snippet I used already contained a lot the code of and I just went with it.

```
<?php

function my_recent_posts_shortcode($atts)
{
    $q = new WP_Query(
        array('post_type' => 'advertisements', 'posts_per_page' => '1')
    );

    $list = '<div class="row col-offset-2" style="background-color: #182027;color:white;padding:1em;color:white;">';
    $buttonlink = get_field('page_link');
    $buttonURL = get_field('custom_url');
    if ($buttonURL != '')
    {
        $buttonfinallink = $buttonURL;
    }
    else
    {
        $buttonfinallink = $buttonlink;
    }

    while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();

        $list .= '<div class="col-md-9">
                    <h2 style="margin-bottom:0.3em;font-size:16px;">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
                    <br /><div style="color:#ccc;font-size:14px;">' . get_field('content') . '</div>
                    <a href="' . echo $buttonURL . '" class="link" style="margin-top:0.8em; font-size:0.8em;">' . get_field('link_label') . '</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="' . get_field('image') . '" style="max-height:75px;"></div>';

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    return $list . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode('incontent-ad', 'my_recent_posts_shortcode');

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have a syntax error. As you are concatenating string then you
>   don't need to `echo` it.

```
//...
//...
while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
    $buttonfinallink = '';
    $buttonlink = get_field('page_link');
    $buttonURL = get_field('custom_url');
    if ($buttonURL != '') {
        $buttonfinallink = $buttonURL;
    } else {
        $buttonfinallink = $buttonlink;
    }

    $list .= '<div class="col-md-9">
                    <h2 style="margin-bottom:0.3em;font-size:16px;">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>
                    <br /><div style="color:#ccc;font-size:14px;">' . get_field('content') . '</div>
                    <a href="' . $buttonfinallink . '" class="link" style="margin-top:0.8em; font-size:0.8em;">' . get_field('link_label') . '</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3"><img src="' . get_field('image') . '" style="max-height:75px;"></div>';

endwhile;
//...
//...
```

Comment: Hmm thanks. Just noticed another typo. In that section it should not be $buttonURL but $buttonfinallink. However in that case it still wont load the values of either $buttonlink or $buttonurl. I dont get it. page_link and custom_url are the exact field names. If i use get_field('custom_url') directly that works but as a variable for some reason it doesnt.

Comment: and one more thing `page_link` and `custom_url` will be same for all ads?

Comment: Well the page wouldnt load at all. It just stays white. One more possibly salient details is that i've put this as a plugin instead of at the bottom of function.php. 

The value of page_link and custom_url will change dependent on which post it loads..... oh could that be the reason? That i tried to define the variables even before it knows where to get the values from? So i might have to place it after the while($q... or does it already knows which post after wp_query?

Comment: I have updated my answer. and yes you have to put those inside `while` loop. And it does not matter that you keep above code in plugin or `functions.php`; if your plugin is active it will work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort @Raunak Gupta. It works now thanks to you.